# Get all data based on lowest 2 value from 2 column using sql query

Tags: mysql

I have following data in mysql table called `leadboard`:

```
time_taken        moves
=======================
0 mins 37 secs    20
0 mins 38 secs    15
```

Now I want to get all data from lowest to highest value based on that 2 column. **Means,** Lowest **time_taken**, and lowest **moves** should be on top.

So what should its return as the leaderboard result?

```
0 mins 37 secs    20
0 mins 38 secs    15
```

OR

```
0 mins 38 secs    15
0 mins 37 secs    20
```

?

I am using the following query :

```
$leadboard->rowQuery("SELECT * FROM leadboard ORDER BY moves ASC, time_taken ASC  LIMIT 10");
```

and it returns me:

```
0 mins 38 secs    15
0 mins 37 secs    20
```

Is that correct or I need changes my query?

Comment: You will need a natural string sort for your `time_taken` column. Otherwise 10 mins will be considered "smaller" than 9 mins.

Comment: I believe you query is right have you tried what is the output when to rows have matching number of moves ? try with more rows to see if it behaves as expected/needed

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I don't understand.

Comment: @ShibbirAhmed - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez let me check it

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez if the moves is equal then data is showing from lowest to highest based on time_taken. So that is that okay?

Comment: @ShibbirAhmed that depends on what you need, how do you untie records when they have the same amount on moves, i guess based on time sounds good

Comment: Thanks @MauricioGraciaGutierrez for the idea.